# Topology proof question?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-construction

How to prove that $X_1 := \{(x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\} / (S^1 × \{0\} )$ is homeomorphic to the union $X_2$ of two tangent spheres minus two points?

What I know:

Let  $C$ be cylinder $:=\{(x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$,

$ (S^1 \times \{0\})$ collapses the circle in the $xy$-plane to a point which leaves a double cone connected by a single point which is given by the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$.
So, firstly, we need to find an identification turning the cylinder into the infinite cone.

Could I please get a hint on how to do that?

Looking at the coordinate function for z, would it be the homeomorphism between 0 to (0,+infinity)

f_z: {0} $\to$ (0,+ infinity)

z $\to$ 1/z

Comment: You or whoever made the edit seem to have missed some curly parentheses in the definition of $\;X_1\;$. Is that an infinite cyclinder *over* (i.e., quotient space) $\;S^1\times\{0\}\;$ , or what? And then you use $\;X_1\;$ *again* ...!?

Comment: It is S^1 x {0} but the curly brackets are not showing up..

Comment: Yes, I see. Some days now the site's MathJax hasn't been working properly. Thank you. Yet, why do you have that slash "/" there? This misleads. Shouldn't it be an equality sign?

Comment: They've fixed it now.

Comment: In your first line there's **still** appears a backslash "/" before $\;(S^1\times \{0\})\;$ ? Why? Shouldn't this be an equality sign instead?

Comment: This is how it is written in the question.

Comment: Then $\;X_1\;$ is **not** the cylinder you denote afterwards as $\;C\;$ ...!

Comment: But isn't x^2+y^2=1 in R^3 the equation of an unbounded cylinder?

Comment: @Useer Yes, it is: that is $\;C\;$ , *not* $\;X_1\;$, which seems to be an infinite cylinder minus a circle, yet I still cannot understand what does $\;S^1\times\{0\}\;$ really means *in the three dimensional real space* . Perhaps they meant $\;\{(x,y,0)\;:\;\;x^2+y^2=1\}\;$ ?

Comment: Would it be the unit circle in the xy plane?

Comment: That's what I think: the quotient space of the infinite cylinder $\;C\;$ by the unit circle on the $\;xy$- plane...

Comment: Could you tell me how to find the map the x,y,z in X_1 to turn it into an infinite cone?

Comment: This is pretty confusing for me. Perhaps someone else with more practice can help: the space $\;S^1\times\{0\}\;$ can be seen, imo, as a circle (which exists in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ or in any other plane) "coordinated" by that $\;0\;$ there, yet I can't understand how this fits in $\;\Bbb R^3\;$. Sorry.

Comment: @Timbuc The set $S^1 \times \{0\} = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 = 1, z = 0\}$ is identified to a point (so we have a modding out by an equivalence relation), hence the forward slash (it's a standard notation, if $X$ is a space and $A \subset X$, we define $X / A$ this way).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks a lot. I know what a quotient space is and what the backslash means (read the above comments), yet I just couldn't understand why $\;S^1\times \{0\}\;$ is the unit circle on the $\;xy$-plane, though I and the OP already "suspected" it is what you say it is. Is it perhaps a wide agreement in (algebraic or pointwise) topology?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the two spheres $N$ and $S$, each with radius 1, $N$ with center $(0, 0, 1)$ and $S$ with center $(0, 0, -1)$. Now look at the following map from $C$ to $N \cup S$:

For $(x, y, z) \in C$ with $z > 0$, define $h(x, y, z)$ to be the intersection of the segment from $(x, y, z)$ to $(0, 0, 0)$ with $N$; for $z < 0$, define it to be the intersection of the segment with $S$. (In brief: consider $h$ as "the inverse of stereographic projection from the origin of $A \cup B$ to $C$").

For $(x, y, 0) \in C$, define $h(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)$.

I'm going to assume you can prove that $h$ is continuous, and that its image misses only the north pole of $N$ and the south pole of $S$. Let's say that $N$, without its north pole, is $N_0$ and similarly for $S_0$. (Note that $N_0 \cup S_0 = X_2$.) So $h: C \to S_0 \cup N_0$ is a surjection.

Now all that's left is to see that $h$ passes to the quotient. Well, $h$, restricted to 
the $z = 0$ circle of $C$, is the constant map to the origin. So we get a map $\bar{h}: X_1 \to S_0 \cup N_0$ defined by 
$$
\bar{h}(\pi(p)) = h(p)
$$
where $\pi :C \to X_1$ is the projection onto the quotient.

$\bar{h}$ is the required homeomorphism.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but what is A and B?

Comment: My mistake: those were my earlier names for "N" and "S", and I used them by mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. Is the mapping i have added into the question for turning the cylinder into an infinite cone correct?

Comment: The domain of your supposed homeomorphism seems to be the single number 0, while the codomain is an interval, so that doesn't really make sense. And there's no homoemorphism from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$ that carries the cylinder $C$ onto the double-cone at the origin in the way you're hoping, because it would have to send the whole $S^1 \times \{0\}$ to the origin, hence would not be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please tell me why neither space(X_1 or X_2) is locally Euclidean?

Comment: Look at a neighborhood of the origin in either $X_1$ or $X_2$: deleting the origin will cause this neighborhood to separate into two components. But deleting a single point from the interior of an open disk in $\mathbb R^2$ never does this. Hence your neighborhood of the origin cannot be homeomorphic to an open disk in $\mathbb R^2$.